# Beautiful Soup 4: Remove comment tag and its content

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

The page that I'm scraping contains these HTML codes. How do I remove the comment tag `<!-- -->` along with its content with bs4?

```html
<div class="foo">
cat dog sheep goat
<!-- 
<p>NewPP limit report
Preprocessor node count: 478/300000
Post‐expand include size: 4852/2097152 bytes
Template argument size: 870/2097152 bytes
Expensive parser function count: 2/100
ExtLoops count: 6/100
</p>
-->
</div>
```

Comment: To what end? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) (solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3507360/771848)):

> PageElement.extract() removes a tag or string from the tree. It
>   returns the tag or string that was extracted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

data = """<div class="foo">
cat dog sheep goat
<!--
<p>test</p>
-->
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

div = soup.find('div', class_='foo')
for element in div(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    element.extract()

print soup.prettify()
```

As a result you get your `div` without comments:

```
<div class="foo">
    cat dog sheep goat
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic..this works like charm but I'm having problem trying to understand `div(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):`. Can you elaborate how that works?

Comment: @Flint yup, it is basically a shorter way to call `find_all()`.

Comment: @Flint in order to understand what `text` means here - see [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument). Hope that helps.

Comment: This works like a charm for the whole document soup as well. I use html5lib (speed is not important, but validation is).

Answer (score 8):

Usually modifying the bs4 parse tree is unnecessary.  You can just get the div's text, if that's what you wanted:

```
soup.body.div.text
Out[18]: '\ncat dog sheep goat\n\n'
```

`bs4` separates out the comment.  However if you really need to modify the parse tree:

```
from bs4 import Comment

for child in soup.body.div.children:
    if isinstance(child,Comment):
        child.extract()
```

Comment: Looks simple enough but I can't work your code in case where my html codes in the question above were result of .find() eg `bar = soup.find("div", class_="foo")`

Comment: `text` help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55705414/3967750)
If you are looking for solution in BeautifulSoup version 3 [BS3 Docs - Comment](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20Parse%20Tree)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""Hello! <!--I've got to be nice to get what I want.-->""")
comment = soup.find(text=re.compile("if"))
Comment=comment.__class__
for element in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    element.extract()
print soup.prettify()
```

Answer (score 2):

Little late, but i have compared main answers on internet so you can choose whats best for you:

**we can do the removal of comments by regex also**

```
soupstr=str(soup)
result=re.sub(r'<!.*?->','', soupstr)
```

but this method of regex is 4 times slower when we convert soup to string via `soupstr=str(soup)` than  `findAll...isinstance(x,Comment)` as written by others.

But is 5 times faster when you have html as string and apply regex processing to remove comments.

**benchmark result after running functions 1000 times:**

```
bs4,isinstance(x,Comment) method: time: 0.01193189620971680ms
soup convert to string and apply regex: 0.04188799858093262ms
apply regex before converting to soup : 0.00195980072021484ms (WINNER!)
```

maybe you can use pure regex in cases where you dont want to use isinstance method.

**for people who need quick result and dont want to read full answer, here is the copy paste function ready to run:**

```
def remove_comments_regexmethod(soup): 
    #soup argument can be string or bs4.beautifulSoup instance it will auto convert to string, please prefer to input as (string) than (soup) if you want highest speed
    if not isinstance(soup,str): 
        soup=str(soup)
    return re.sub(r'<!.*?->','', soup)#returns a string
```