# How to remove HTML comments using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove HTML comments from an html text

```html
<h1>heading</h1> <!-- comment-with-hyphen --> some text <-- con --> more text <hello></hello> more text
```

should result in:

```html
<h1>heading</h1> some text <-- con --> more text <hello></hello> more text
```

Comment: Using regular expressions on a limited, known set of HTML may be appropriate. However, you should be aware that there are countless cases where it will break and it is generally not advised.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question? If you are working on a "known set of HTML" this was a legit question.

Comment: Consider using a HTML specific library like Beatiful Soup, like this other question-solutions suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299557/beautifulsoup-4-remove-comment-tag-and-its-content

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't ignore Carriage return.

```
re.sub("(<!--.*?-->)", "", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Why shouldn't we remove the carriage returns as well?

Comment: huazhihao's answer matches comments that have carriage returns within the comment. One of the other answers lacks flags=re.MULTILINE

Comment: actually should be `re.DOTALL`, not `re.MULTILINE`. It's `re.DOTALL` who matches `\n` on `.`

Answer (score 5):

```
html = re.sub(r"<!--(.|\s|\n)*?-->", "", html)
```

re.sub basically find the matching instance and replace with the second arguments. For this case, `<!--(.|\s|\n)*?-->` matches anything start with `<!--` and end with `-->`. The dot and ? means anything, and the \s and \n add the cases of muti line comment.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! If the OP could understand your code by itself, he probably would not be asking. Please explain what it does, so that it provides value for those who would need to look up a regex.

Answer (score 3):

Finally came up with this option:

`re.sub("(<!--.*?-->)", "", t)`

Adding the `?` makes the search non-greedy and does not combine multiple comment tags.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex. Use an XML parser instead, the one in the standard library is more than sufficient.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
html = ET.parse("comments.html")
ET.dump(html) # Dumps to stdout
ET.write("no-comments.html", method="html") # Write to a file
```

Comment: While this is good advice, the performance of XML parsers is much, much, much slower than this sort of regex.

Answer (score 1):

```python
re.sub("(?s)<!--.+?-->", "", s)
```

or

```
re.sub("<!--.+?-->", "", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex `<![^<]*>`

Comment: Your regex matches too much -- note that the question has an example "<-- con -->", which is not an HTML comment.

Comment: @GregLindahl this regex didn't match "<-- con -->" and returned the result as the OP expected.

Comment: This won't match a comment with an HTML tag inside of it, like <!-- <br/> -->