# Python method to remove any text within specified tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I'm handling HTML code in Python and would like to remove all comments (starting tag `<!--` and ending tag `-->`. Is there a function, method, or library that can help me achieve this?

Comment: You could use regex to accomplish this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208186/how-to-remove-html-comments-using-regex-in-python

Comment: Also, you could use BeautifulSoup, a library focused on dealing with HTML as this other answer solves https://stackoverflow.com/a/23299678/3521714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably string manipulation. Just convert your html to a string and run:

```
import re
html_cleaned = re.sub("\\<\\!--.*--\\>", "", myhtml)
```

Then convert back to whatever you are using for html.

The re module is python's implementation of regular [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be a great library to use to remove specific elements:

```
html = re.sub(r"<!--(.|\s|\n)*?-->", "", html)
```

The re.sub function takes two arguments: The first one scans for those tags, and the second replaces the tags with whatever string input.