# Remove Comments from HTML Tags

Tags: html, python-2.7, tags, beautifulsoup

Reffering to [How can I strip comment tags from HTML using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507283/how-can-i-strip-comment-tags-from-html-using-beautifulsoup) , I am trying to remove the comments from the below Tag

```
>>> h
<h4 class="col-sm-4"><!-- react-text: 124 -->52 Week High/Low:<!-- /react-text --><b><!-- react-text: 126 --> ₹ <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 127 -->394.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 128 --> / ₹ <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 129 -->252.10<!-- /react-text --></b></h4>
```

My code -

```
comments = h.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
print h
```

But the search for comments results in nothing. I want to extract the 2 values - **"52 Week High/Low:"** and **"₹ 394.00 / ₹ 252.10"** from the above Tag.

I also tried removing the tags form the entire html using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
print soup
```

But the comments are still there.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `Python2.7` and `BeautifulSoup4`? If not the latter, I would install `BeautifulSoup4`.

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

This following script works for me. I just copied and pasted from your question above and ran it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = """<h4 class="col-sm-4"><!-- react-text: 124 -->52 Week High/Low:<!-- /react-text --><b><!-- react-text: 126 --> ₹ <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 127 -->394.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 128 --> / ₹ <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 129 -->252.10<!-- /react-text --></b></h4>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))

# nit: It isn't good practice to use a list comprehension only for its
# side-effects. (Wastes space constructing an unused list)
for comment in comments:
   comment.extract()

print soup
```

> Note: It's a good thing you posted the `print` statement. Wouldn't have known it was Python 2 otherwise. Posting the Python version helps too.

Comment: Quick Q - Can i not use the tag directly here - comments = h.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)) ? h is a tag and has a findAll method defined. So ideally it should work.. But i still get empty comments object. Do we need to explicitly convert the Tag back so html and soup?

Comment: It works when i use your code as is. But when i apply the comment search on every tag in loop, (Each Tag in h).. it fails.. which is very odd..

Comment: Got it working at the full HTML level. the tag still give me empty comments array :-(