# Python How to get a specific code in website using re

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7, web

I'm trying to make python challange.
http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html
Ok. I know, I can just copy paste the code from source to a txt file and make things like that but I want to take it from net for improving myself. (+ I have done it already) I have tried

```
re.findall(r"<!--(.*?)-->,html)
```

But it doesn't get anything.
If you want my full code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests,re
link = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html"
x = requests.get(link)
codes = re.findall(r"<!--(.*)-->",str(x.content))
print codes
```

Also I tried making it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests,re
link = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html"
x = requests.get(link)
codes = re.findall("<!--\n(.*)\n-->",str(x.content))
print codes
```

Now it finds the text but still can't get that mess :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "that mess". You should include all of the details of the challenge within this post, instead of linking users to the pythonchallenge post.

Either way, if you set the regex to be in single-line mode, `//s`, then the dot character, `.`, should match newlines, `/n`, as well. This obviates the `\n(.+)\n` construction in your regex, which may solve your problem.

Here's a [link to a working regex example](https://regex101.com/r/zE4oQ7/1).

Here is the modified python 2.7 code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests, re
link = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html"
x = requests.get(link)
codes = re.findall("<!--(.*?)-->", str(x.content), re.S)
print codes[1]
```

Note the `re.S`, `(.*?)`, and `codes[1]` modifications.

- `re.S` is python's flag for `//s`
- `(.*?)` makes the `*` quantifier non-greedy
- `codes[1]` prints the second set of content found within HTML comments (since `findall(..)` matches 2 and returns an array of both sets).

Comment: Please provide a python2.7 example.

Comment: In the website they introduced that code with name "mess" also you don't need an account to go that website. Btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is the answer working for what you're after? It seemed to work for me.

Comment: Also I know it is bad to make questions in question but can you explain me  the (.*?) Is that a prefix like "Get everything here"?

Answer (score 2):

I would use an *HTML parser* instead. You can [find comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3507360/771848) in HTML with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


link = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html"
response = requests.get(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

code = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))[-1]
print(code.strip())
```

Comment: I tried using bs4 but it was too hard to control bs4 :( also I'm likely new to python so I can't mostly understand lambda's. Can you make a function?

Comment: @Dr.UK well, if you have HTML source to parse, you [should not be using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) in general. As for you question, `lambda` is just a short way to write a function. You rarely need to pass functions in BeautifulSoup like in this case, BeautifulSoup is quite a convenient and easy to work with library. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Dr.UK, if you find bs4 too hard to control  then good luck with nested elements and a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve:

```
codes = re.findall("/<!--(.*?)-->/s",str(x.content))
```

"s" find with whitespace and breakline