# BeautifulSoup4 unable to find "a" tag by searching for text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Example HTML

```
<a class="accordion-item__link" href="/identity-checking/individual"><!-- react-text: 178 -->Australia<!-- /react-text --></a>
```

When I run

```
soup.find("a", text="Australia")
```

it returns nothing.

If I run
`soup.find("a", href="/identity-checking/individual")` it finds the tag.
`soup.find("a", href="/identity-checking/individual").text` also returns 'Australia'

is it something to do with the  comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, detecting the tag text gets flipped when there is an `xml` comment.

You can use this as a workaround:

```
[ele for ele in soup('a') if ele.text == 'Australia']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to find a method that sticks to the `find` method as it is the most convenient & adaptable. The problem here is that the HTML comments mess up the engine. Manually remove comments would be helpful.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

bs = BeautifulSoup(
    """
    <a class="accordion-item__link" href="/identity-checking/individual"><!-- react-text: 178 -->Australia<!-- /react-text --></a>
    """,
    "lxml"
)
# find all HTML comments and remove
comments = bs.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]

r = bs.find('a', text='Australia')
print(r)
#  <a class="accordion-item__link" href="/identity-checking/individual">Australia</a>
```

The method to remove comments came from here [How can I strip comment tags from HTML using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507283/how-can-i-strip-comment-tags-from-html-using-beautifulsoup/3507360)

If the comments are meant to be preserved, you may work on a copy of soup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract the text after finding the tag, that is:

```
result = ""
for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    if tag.text == "Australia":
        result = tag
```