# Accessing Tags within HTML comments

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been familiarizing myself with web scraping with Python, via BS4. I have not been able to find a solution to  DOM tags that are embedded within comments. For example, when trying to get data from a .html page (https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/GSW/2018/lineups/), inspecting a table on the page shows:

```
<div class='table_outer_container"> ... </div>
```

Which I would normally be able to grab using BeautifulSoup. However, when I view the actual page source, said table is encased in comment tags:

```
<!--

<div class='table_outer_container"> ... </div>

-->
```

I have been unable to find a way to access it through BS4. Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/q/3507283/3491475 answers this.

Comment: As far as I understand it this is referring to the extraction of comments, which is certainly part of the problem. However, when using this method it returns their contents as a string, which cannot undergo further parsing with BS4. I was wondering if there is anyway to extract comments and parse those further as if they were DOM, rather than just text

Comment: *"it returns their contents as a string, which cannot undergo further parsing with BS4"* - Hmm... parsing HTML strings into trees is what BS4 *does*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the comment tags before feeding the html into bs4.

**Make sure we have the right strings for the replace function**

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/GSW/2018/lineups/")
print(page.text.count("""<!--\n   <div class="table_outer_container">"""),page.text.count("""</div>\n-->"""))
# out: 8 8
```

**Replace the strings**

```
no_open_tag = page.text.replace("""<!--\n   <div class="table_outer_container">""","""<div class="table_outer_container">""")
no_close_tag = no_open_tag.replace("""</div>\n-->""","</div>")
print(no_close_tag.count("""<!--\n   <div class="table_outer_container">"""),no_close_tag.count("""</div>\n-->"""))
# out: 0 0
```

**Feed into bs4**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(no_close_tag, "html5lib")
print(len(soup.findAll("div", {"class":"table_outer_container"})))
# out: 8
```

We now can parse all 8 commented divs.

Comment: Wow had just started to look a bit deeper into requests lately... perfect. Thank you